# Why classmethod are create new one for the each instance in python

Tags: python, class-variables

While working with oops in python, the class variables are created once when the class is created. The instance, instead of creating new one they use the already created one when the class is created. But, the class methods are created each time when the instance are created. Why the both are working differently.

Comment: "The instance, instead of creating new one they use the already created one when the class is created." I don't understand what that means... Nor " But, the class methods are created each time when the instance are created. Why the both are working differently."

Answer (score 1):

Its the variables that are created or not created on instance creations. The methods are defined just once with your class definition. The values that are passed to the method. eg `self` or `class instance` in case of class methods change depending on the type of method.